# I have an error with a math operation Java?

Tags: java, string, integer

I created a code that is meant to accept a user-input then add 5 to it, this is the code. When I enter any number, It returns 0. EDIT: I moved the reCalculate down under main, nothing changes

```
package files;
import java.util.*;
public class CalculatorTest {
static Scanner userFirstNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
static int numberReCalculated;

public static int reCalculate(int a){
int numberReCalculated = a + 5;
return numberReCalculated;
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int bobson;
        System.out.print("Enter a number, I will do the rest : ");
        bobson = userFirstNumber.nextInt();
        reCalculate(bobson);
        System.out.println(numberReCalculated);

    }



 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration of `int numberReCalculated = a + 5;` shadows the field declaration `static int numberReCalculated;`. Either change `int numberReCalculated = a + 5;` to `numberReCalculated = a + 5;`, or rewrite the entire code to be idiomatic and organized:

```
public class CalculatorTest {
    static Scanner userFirstNumber = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int reCalculate(int a){
        return a + 5;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int input;
        System.out.print("Enter a number, I will do the rest : ");
        input = userFirstNumber.nextInt();
        int result = reCalculate(bobson);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

I have no idea how "bobson" is a descriptive and self-documenting variable name.